# UITableview section collapses on itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, ios8

So I have a static table view and I just manually built a section in IB and it worked completely fine in iOS 7 and in iOS 8 it completely collapsed in on itself:

Here's what its supposed to look like:

[image]

And this is what's happening:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what's going on.  The tree looks fine.  I cut and pasted it back in just to make sure.  I built the same source with iOS 7 and no problem.

Comment: Are you returning any value in - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section?

Comment: No and I don't see why I should have to since I'm doing it all in IB and the other two sections are fine.